# Why doesn't my 'find' work like I expect using -exec?

Tags: unix, shell, find

I'm trying to remove all the .svn directories from a working directory.

I thought I would just use find and rm like this:

```
find . -iname .svn -exec 'rm -rf {}' \;
```

But the result is:

find: rm -rf ./src/.svn: No such file or directory

Obviously the file exists, or find wouldn't find it... What am I missing?

Comment: You should really use -delete with find, if you can.  Don't forget to use -depth with find when using -delete or rm -rf.

Comment: Looks like -delete implies -depth according to the man page.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You shouldn't put the `rm -rf {}` in single quotes.

As you've quoted it the shell is treating all of the arguments to `-exec` it as a command rather than a command plus arguments, so it's looking for a file called `"rm -rf ./src/.svn"` and not finding it.

Try:

```
find . -iname .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: I think that the last time I used -exec it was for a grep which I needed to quote the regex, and so I had that in my head. Thanks all!

Comment: I said "Don't need" because it looked like Sam thought he needed to.  However, I see that this is ambiguous and will edit.

Answer (score 7):

Just by-the-bye, you should probably get out of the habit of using -exec for things that can be done to multiple files at once.  For instance, I would write that out of habit as

```
find . -iname .svn -print | xargs rm -rf
```

or, since I'm now using a Macintosh and more likely to encounter file or directory names with spaces in them

```
find . -iname .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

"xargs" makes sure that "rm" is invoked only once every "N" files, where "N" is usually 20.  That's not a huge win in this case, because rm is small, but if the program you wanted to execute on every file was large or did a lot of processing on start up, it could make things a lot faster.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check out the man page for xargs, and for the record, I'm on a mac, too. w00t!

Comment: Alternatively, you can end the -exec clause of find with "\+" instead of "\;", which is equivalent to using -print0 and piping to xargs.

Comment: @Adam, that must be fairly new?  Mind you, I switched to using args back in the days of Ultrix on MicroVax, so "new" might mean "in the last 15-20 years".

Answer (score 3):

maybe its just me, but the old find & rm script *does not* work on my current config, a la:

> find /data/bin/test -type d -mtime +10 -name "[0-9]*" -exec rm -rf {} \;

whereas the xargs solution *does*, a la:

> find /data/bin/test -type d -mtime +10 -name  '[0-9]*' -print | xargs rm -rf ;

no idea why, but i've updated my scriptLib so i dont spend another couple hours beating
my head on something so simple....

(running RHEL under kernel-2.6.18-194.11.3.el5)

**EDIT**:  found out why - my RHEL distro defaults vi to insert the dreaded cr into line breaks (whch breaks the command) - following suggestions from nx5000 & jliagre at linuxquestions.org, added the following to ~/.vimrc:

> :set fileformat=unix
>
> map <F4> :set fileformat=unix<CR>
>
> map <F5> :set fileformat=dos<CR>

which allows the behavior to pivot on the F4/F5.

to check whether CR's are embedded in your file:

> head -1 scriptFile.sh | od -c | head -1

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-213617/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the svn command as follows:

```
svn export <url-to-repo> <dest-path>
```

[Look here for more info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html).

Comment: Awesome. I figured I could do that but I didn't know how to export the working directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find . -iname .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

and that probably ought to work IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass anything you want in quotes, with the following trick.

```
find . -iname .svn -exec bash -c 'rm -rf {}' \;
```

The `exec` option will be happy to see that you're simply calling an executable with an argument, but your argument will be able to contain a script of basically any size and shape.

```
find . -iname .svn -exec bash -c '
  ls -l "{}" | wc -l
' \;
```